# c++ read array cin error

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I haven't coded in c++ for over a year, I can't see the error in this code.

It says the cin function is having an error, `no such operator >>`

```
int main()
{
    double * array[25];
    bool exitCode = false;
    cout <<"Enter in your Array"<<endl;
    do{
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            cout<< "Enter your float number";
            cin >> array[i];

            cout << "Are there any more inputs?: ( Y or N )";
            cin >> exitCode; // error is here
        }
    }while(exitCode == false);

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're including the following :

```
<fstream>
<istream>
<iostream>
<string>
```

Comment: don't forget `using namespace std;` :p

Comment: Agreed! hehe I assume he was since he wasn't getting any error on the **cout** ! Thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double array1[25];
    char exitCode;
    cout <<"Enter in your Array"<<endl;
    do{
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            cout<< "Enter your float number";
            cin >> array1[i];

            cout << "Are there any more inputs?: ( Y or N )";
            cin >> exitCode; // error is here
        }
    }while(exitCode == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

i wonder why you're using a pointer and an array when you only store it on the array(and not using the pointer) >.>

and thus, `exitCode` is `boolean`(which i think is the reason why it's got an error)

Answer (score 1):

Lets take this line by line:

Change

> double * array[25];

to

> double array[25];

Reason:
`double *` is a pointer to a double, so in the original you declared an array of 25 pointers, but there is no reason why you should use pointers here. You want an array of 25 doubles.

```
do{
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
```

You declared a for loop inside the while loop. You only need one loop in your example.

> cout << "Are there any more inputs?: ( Y or N )";

You are asking for character input from the user. However `cin >> exitCode;` is reading a bool, you probably wanted to read a `char`.

> return array;

Your returning an `array`, main returns an `int`.

Here is the code with the above fixes and proper includes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double array[25];
cout <<"Enter in your Array"<<endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    cout<< "Enter your float number";
    cin >> array[i];

    cout << "Are there any more inputs?: ( Y or N )";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    if (c == 'N')
    {
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared 'array' to be be an array of pointers to doubles. I doubt that is what you actually want, but, anyway, the '<<' operator on 'cin' doesn't support that, so this is invalid:

```
cin >> array[i];
```

You would have to change it to

```
cin >> *array[i];
```

to make it compile. (It won't run due to the pointers not being initialized.)

I think what you probably want is for 'array' just to be an array of doubles.

Comment: I know. That's why I said that's probably not what he wants.

Comment: Well, it will compile, but the program will crash when it dereferences an uninitialized pointer.